# Excel VBA: locate details in one sheet, then copy (append) to another

Tags: vba, excel

*I would really appreciate your help with building some macro logic. I've messed around modifying recorded macros in the past, but am not familiar enough with VBA to build something from scratch. I've looked over the many examples here as well (mindboggling!), but did not find anything close enough to what I need to do... 
I know it probably only takes a few lines of code - which makes it even more frustrating. Can someone please put me on the right track?*

I have a single workbook with two sheets. Sheet1 contains a long list (~25k rows, but variable) of product details. Column A has the product ID, then columns B through G hold specific details on each product. Sheet2 is similar, again with product ID in column A and (different) properties in columns B through E. Sheet2 is much smaller, at about 100 rows (also variable).

What I need to do is to loop through the products (rows) in Sheet2, find the corresponding Product ID in Sheet1, and copy/paste the product properties in Sheet1 (B through G) to Sheet2 (to the right of the existing properties, so starting at column F in my example) - effectively merging all product properties in Sheet2.

*I would be very grateful if one of you wizzards can provide skeleton code for that....*

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free coding service - you have to show us some sweat. what have you tried? what have you researched...

Comment: I appreciate that, NirMH. Believe it or not, this kept me busy for 2 days... I've been trying to record macros and modify the generated code (my usual mode of operation) - but cannot record a macro that completes the work to a point where I can finish the code. I've copied/pasted many examples from this site, trying to make it work but realised I don't understand all the 'object.value' references and VBA functions. And perhaps I should struggle for even more hours to learn and understand better, but I hoped the community could put me on the right track (just as a recorded macro would do)...

Comment: If that's the case, how about you show us what you've tried and ask what's wrong with it and how you should edit it to make it work properly? Then the question would be about fixing your issues in the code rather than asking us to provide a ready solution for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the two ranges from your two sheets, loop through them and find matches in product id, then just copy the values from the first sheet into the second one. Also replace the ranges to match your conditions.

```
Sub search()
Dim cell As Range, rng As Range, rng2 As Range, cell1 As Range, n As Integer, m As  Integer
Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A2:A9")
Set rng2 = Sheet2.Range("A2:A3")

n = 1
m = 1
For Each cell In rng
    n = n + 1
For Each cell1 In rng2
    m = m + 1
        If cell.Value = cell1.Value Then
            Sheets("Sheet2").Range("F" & m & ":J" & m).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & n & ":F" & n).Value
        End If
    Next cell1
    m = 1
Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: IolandaAB - thank you so much! I was collecting some of my autogenerated-and-then-modified code as the previous respondents suggested - but it is all embarrassing complex (and not even working...) compared to the elegant solution you provided. I just knew there had to be a simple and elegant solution, but my last programming was in Pascal (does that reveal my age?), and I can't get my hands around this object-oriented VBA stuff. I really appreciate your help and the time you spent on it.